# curl command failing in a script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, windows-server-2012

I am new to batch scripting. I am trying to create a batch wrapper script which uses curl to get HTTP code for a site

The curl command works in CMD:

`curl -s -w "%{http_code}" https://www.sample.com/`

However, if I put this in a batch script, it throws an error:

> curl: no URL specified!
>
> curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Below is the batch script:

`ECHO OFF`

`curl -s -w "%{http_code}" https://www.sample.com/`

Is there anything I am doing wrong. Please advise.

Comment: The `%` character has a special meaning for command line parameters and FOR parameters. [To treat a percent as a regular character in a batch script](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), double it: `curl -s -w "%%{http_code}" https://www.sample.com/`

Comment: Unfortunately, the additional % character did not help. I get the output as %{http_code} instead of the value of http_code.

Comment: Again: if `curl -s -w "%{http_code}" https://www.sample.com/` runs in `cmd` then a **batch script** equivalent is `curl -s -w "%%{http_code}" https://www.sample.com/` (use `echo ON` to see the resulting command).

Comment: Thanks very much. That works. The incorrect result I was seeing was because the site was down. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use curl**.exe**, so :

```
curl.exe  -s -w "%{http_code}" https://www.sample.com/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).